# Dynamically unlink a google form from a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I am creating a dynamic form for a Google spreadsheet. Each time I generate the form I get an error popup saying "there's already a Form attached to the spreadsheet". I then have to manually unlink the form before I can use it.

Is there a method that will allow me to programmatically unlink the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating it? Please post some code along with your questions.

But to "detach a form" from a spreadsheet, you have to open the form using `FormApp` and call [`removeDestination()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#removeDestination%28%29)